# Postgres index not using correct plan

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-10

My postgresql version is 10.6. I have created an index but that is not used for all where clause condition check. Below are more details :

```
Create index concurrently ticket_created_at_portal_id_created_by_id_assigned_group_id_idx on ticket(created_at, portal_id, created_by_id, assigned_group);
```

```
EXPLAIN (analyze true, verbose true, costs true, buffers true, timing true ) select * from ticket where status is not null
and (assigned_group in ('447') or created_by_id in ('39731566'))
and portal_id=8
and created_at>='2020-12-07T03:00:10.973'
and created_at<='2021-02-05T03:00:10.973'
order by updated_at DESC limit 10;


                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=18975.23..18975.25 rows=10 width=638) (actual time=278.340..278.345 rows=10 loops=1)
   Output: id, action, assigned_agent, assigned_at, assigned_group, attachments, closed_at, created_at, created_by_email, created_by_id, description, first_response_time, parent_id, portal_id, priority, reopened_at, resolution_id, resolved_at, resolved_by_id, resource_id, resource_type, source, status, subject, tags, ticket_category, ticket_id, ticket_sub_category, ticket_sub_sub_category, type, updated_at, custom_fields, updated_by_id, first_assigned_at, mode, sla_breached, agent_assist_tags, comm_vendor, from_email
   Buffers: shared hit=2280 read=3105
   ->  Sort  (cost=18975.23..18975.45 rows=87 width=638) (actual time=278.338..278.339 rows=10 loops=1)
         Output: id, action, assigned_agent, assigned_at, assigned_group, attachments, closed_at, created_at, created_by_email, created_by_id, description, first_response_time, parent_id, portal_id, priority, reopened_at, resolution_id, resolved_at, resolved_by_id, resource_id, resource_type, source, status, subject, tags, ticket_category, ticket_id, ticket_sub_category, ticket_sub_sub_category, type, updated_at, custom_fields, updated_by_id, first_assigned_at, mode, sla_breached, agent_assist_tags, comm_vendor, from_email
         Sort Key: ticket.updated_at DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 33kB
         Buffers: shared hit=2280 read=3105
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.ticket  (cost=17855.76..18973.35 rows=87 width=638) (actual time=111.871..275.835 rows=1256 loops=1)
               Output: id, action, assigned_agent, assigned_at, assigned_group, attachments, closed_at, created_at, created_by_email, created_by_id, description, first_response_time, parent_id, portal_id, priority, reopened_at, resolution_id, resolved_at, resolved_by_id, resource_id, resource_type, source, status, subject, tags, ticket_category, ticket_id, ticket_sub_category, ticket_sub_sub_category, type, updated_at, custom_fields, updated_by_id, first_assigned_at, mode, sla_breached, agent_assist_tags, comm_vendor, from_email
               Recheck Cond: (((ticket.assigned_group = '447'::bigint) AND (ticket.portal_id = 8)) OR ((ticket.created_at >= '2020-12-07 03:00:10.973'::timestamp without time zone) AND (ticket.created_at <= '2021-02-05 03:00:10.973'::timestamp without time zone) AND (ticket.portal_id = 8) AND (ticket.created_by_id = '39731566'::bigint)))
               Filter: ((ticket.status IS NOT NULL) AND (ticket.created_at >= '2020-12-07 03:00:10.973'::timestamp without time zone) AND (ticket.created_at <= '2021-02-05 03:00:10.973'::timestamp without time zone))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1517
               Heap Blocks: exact=2638
               Buffers: shared hit=2277 read=3105
               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=17855.76..17855.76 rows=291 width=0) (actual time=106.215..106.216 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=336 read=2408
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ticket_assigned_group_portal_id_assigned_agent_idx  (cost=0.00..11.25 rows=282 width=0) (actual time=10.661..10.661 rows=2776 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((ticket.assigned_group = '447'::bigint) AND (ticket.portal_id = 8))
                           Buffers: shared hit=4 read=15
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ticket_created_at_portal_id_created_by_id_assigned_group_id_idx  (cost=0.00..17844.47 rows=9 width=0) (actual time=95.551..95.551 rows=2 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((ticket.created_at >= '2020-12-07 03:00:10.973'::timestamp without time zone) AND (ticket.created_at <= '2021-02-05 03:00:10.973'::timestamp without time zone) AND (ticket.portal_id = 8) AND (ticket.created_by_id = '39731566'::bigint))
                           Buffers: shared hit=332 read=2393
 Planning time: 43.083 ms
 Execution time: 278.556 ms
(25 rows)
```

ticket_created_at_portal_id_created_by_id_assigned_group_id_idx is having all the columns of where clause except status is not null, but still query is using separate index for Index Cond: ((ticket.assigned_group = '447'::bigint) AND (ticket.portal_id = 8)) which is already present in 2nd index ticket_created_at_portal_id_created_by_id_assigned_group_id_idx.

Why it is so? Even when I include status column as well in the index, still query was using 2 index and hen doing a heavy filter on index heap scan.

1. How we can optimize it?

Also I did experiment with indexes of table but still unable to remove indexes. It seems that same columns are repeated in multiple indexes for diff queries, Please help if we can reduce these no of indexes.
**All indexes for table are:**

```
"ticket_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"ticket_ticket_id_idx" UNIQUE, btree (ticket_id)
"uk2uors84i0m8sjxc6oaocuy6oj" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (ticket_id)
"idx_resource_id" btree (resource_id)
"idx_ticket_created_at" btree (created_at)
"ticket_assigned_agent_idx" btree (assigned_agent)
"ticket_assigned_group_idx" btree (assigned_group)
"ticket_assigned_group_portal_id_assigned_agent_idx" btree (assigned_group, portal_id, assigned_agent)
"ticket_created_at_portal_id_created_by_id_assigned_group_id_idx" btree (created_at, portal_id, created_by_id, assigned_group)
"ticket_created_at_portal_id_status_idx" btree (created_at, portal_id, status)
"ticket_id_resolved_at_assigned_group_status_idx" btree (id, resolved_at, assigned_group, status)
```

Comment: @Laurenz Albe:  Please help here.

Answer (score 1):

How easy would it be to use a phone book (sorted by last-name then first-name) to find every one with a first name of "Francis" whose last name starts with a letter between K and T?  Not very easy, because it is not sorted by first name.  You would have to go through the entire middle half of the phone book, reading everyone's first name.

Same here.  When the first column in your index is used in a range/inequality query rather than equality, it makes all the columns after that one much less efficient.  You would want to put the columns used for equality and not in an OR first.  Unfortunately, that is only portal_id.  The best thing to put next would depend on how selective each of those other conditions are which we can't guess from the info provided.

In deciding this, `status IS NULL` would be the same thing as equality, but `status IS NOT NULL` is not as there are any number of values it could be while still being not null, so it is effectively the same as an inequality.  If this condition is highly selective, the best way to incorporate it would be in the WHERE of a partial index.

Because of the OR, you might still be best off with 2 indexes which could be combined in a bitmap or.

```
...(portal_id, assigned_group, created_at) WHERE status IS NOT NULL;
...(portal_id, created_by_id, created_at) WHERE status IS NOT NULL;
```

Another approach would be to avoid fetching and sorting all of the matching rows, by walking rows in order by updated_at using an index and stopping after 10 of them are found.  An index can be used for walking a column in order as long as only things tested for equality (and without ORs) occur before the ORDER BY column, so:

```
...(portal_id, updated_at) WHERE status IS NOT NULL;
```